# Deploying Hybrid ASP.NET webform and MVC project on iis7 - MVC Routing does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing, application-pool, hybrid

**Hi Stackoverflow,**

Im trying to deploy a hybrid ASP.Net Webform/mvc-project onto iis7 but the mvc routing does not work.
This is what i have done so far:

- Added all required mvc-related dlls.(i have double checked bin-catalog to make sure that everythings there on the deployed installation)
- Added MVC wildcard by adding the IsapiModule handler to iis handler mappings.
- The Server has .Net-Framework 3.5 SP1 installed.
- The web site Managed pipeline mode set to classic

Our project requires the app pool to be running in none-integrated pipeline, but im not sure what MVC requires of the app pool, may i run ASP.NET MVC(2) in a none-integrated managed pipeline?

The web application loads and i want to use the MVC-routing to load javascript but the mvc routing does not responde to the request and instead Webforms gives us a 404-response,
this only happens when the project has been deployed onto the server.

**Does anyone has a idea of why the ASP.Net MVC routing does not fire?**

---

Thanks and Best regards,
Mikael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, the installer did not update production web.config,
so there was some missing mvc-required references,
i used [this article](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-aspnet-webforms-and-aspnet-mvc) to find out what was missing, it describes how to setup a hybrid WebForm/Mvc project in a simple way.

**And now im able to run a hybrid webform/mvc-project on iis7 classic without any problem.**